# Spark sortMergeJoin running continuously

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, query-performance, hadoop-partitioning

I am joining two dataframes, but the join is not completing and running many hours. Due to this 1 task is running continuously although 199 tasks are completed within seconds.

I tried, repartition and changing the right and left dataframes as well. But i am seeing similar result. 
What surprises me more, the data size, left is showing 112.5 GB and right is showing 106.2 GB. 
Although i changed left and right dataframes, but in both cases the datasize left was showing 112.5 GB and right was showing 106.2GB and rows from left were increasing slowly.

stddev from left datafram:

```
+----------------------+------------------+----------+
|stddev_samp(count,0,0)|        avg(count)|  count(1)|
+----------------------+------------------+----------+
|     3.787161261654356|1.0046584439496327|1690685363|
+----------------------+------------------+----------+
```

stddev from right dataframe:

```
+----------------------+-----------------+---------+
|stddev_samp(count,0,0)|       avg(count)| count(1)|
+----------------------+-----------------+---------+
|     5.384120090691418|1.029766419089913|835066016|
+----------------------+-----------------+---------+
```

[SQL from Spark UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HCJL.jpg)

== Optimized Logical Plan ==

```
Project [time#265L,event_datetime_EET#248,telia_psn#496L AS psn_key#753L,telia_pdnconnectionsmobileipaddr#493 AS pdnconnectionsmobileipaddr#754,telia_pdnconnectionsmobileipv6addr#494 AS pdnconnectionsmobileipv6addr#755,telia_pdnconnectionsapn#489 AS pdnconnectionsapn#756,telia_pdnconnectionsapnambrdl#490L AS pdnconnectionsapnambrdl#757L,telia_pdnconnectionsapnambrul#491L AS pdnconnectionsapnambrul#758L,telia_pdnconnectionsdefaultbearerebi#492 AS pdnconnectionsdefaultbearerebi#759,telia_pdnconnectionsselectionmode#495 AS pdnconnectionsselectionmode#760,telia_pdnbearersebi#476 AS pdnbearersebi#761,telia_pdnbearerslinkedebi#481 AS pdnbearerslinkedebi#762,telia_pdnbearersbeareresttime#472L AS pdnbearersbeareresttime#763L,telia_pdnbearersdluserplanefteidinterface#473 AS pdnbearersdluserplanefteidinterface#764,telia_pdnbearersdluserplanefteidteid#475L AS pdnbearersdluserplanefteidteid#765L,telia_pdnbearersdluserplanefteidip#474 AS pdnbearersdluserplanefteidip#766,telia_pdnbearersuluserplanefteidinterface#486 AS pdnbearersuluserplanefteidinterface#767,telia_pdnbearersuluserplanefteidteid#488L AS pdnbearersuluserplanefteidteid#768L,telia_pdnbearersuluserplanefteidip#487 AS pdnbearersuluserplanefteidip#769,telia_pdnbearersqosqci#485 AS pdnbearersqosqci#770,telia_pdnbearersprioritylevel#484 AS pdnbearersprioritylevel#771,telia_pdnbearerspreemptioncapability#482 AS pdnbearerspreemptioncapability#772,telia_pdnbearerspreemptionvulnerability#483 AS pdnbearerspreemptionvulnerability#773,telia_pdnbearersgbrmaxbitratedl#479L AS pdnbearersgbrmaxbitratedl#774L,telia_pdnbearersgbrmaxbitrateul#480L AS pdnbearersgbrmaxbitrateul#775L,telia_pdnbearersgbrguaranteedbitratedl#477L AS pdnbearersgbrguaranteedbitratedl#776L,telia_pdnbearersgbrguaranteedbitrateul#478L AS pdnbearersgbrguaranteedbitrateul#777L,imsi#470L,md5ueidentityimsi#257,ueidentityimei#270L,ueidentityimeitac#271,msisdn#258L,md5msisdn#256,rattype_lu#261,locationinfotac#255,locationinfoeci#252,event_year#469,event_month#468,event_day#466,event_hour#467,ingestion_timestamp#471,child_instance_id#465 AS job_instance_id#778]
    +- Join Inner, Some((((imsi#470L = ueidentityimsi#272L) && (telia_psn#496L = psn_key#259L)) && (time#497L = time#265L)))
       :- Project [event_year#469,ingestion_timestamp#471,telia_pdnbearersebi#476,telia_pdnbearersuluserplanefteidinterface#486,telia_pdnbearersgbrguaranteedbitrateul#478L,telia_pdnbearerspreemptioncapability#482,telia_psn#496L,telia_pdnbearerslinkedebi#481,telia_pdnconnectionsdefaultbearerebi#492,telia_pdnconnectionsapn#489,event_hour#467,telia_pdnconnectionsmobileipaddr#493,telia_pdnbearersdluserplanefteidteid#475L,telia_pdnbearersuluserplanefteidip#487,telia_pdnbearersqosqci#485,telia_pdnbearersbeareresttime#472L,telia_pdnbearersprioritylevel#484,child_instance_id#465,event_day#466,telia_pdnconnectionsselectionmode#495,telia_pdnbearersgbrguaranteedbitratedl#477L,time#497L,telia_pdnconnectionsapnambrul#491L,telia_pdnbearersgbrmaxbitrateul#480L,telia_pdnbearerspreemptionvulnerability#483,telia_pdnbearersuluserplanefteidteid#488L,telia_pdnbearersdluserplanefteidinterface#473,telia_pdnbearersgbrmaxbitratedl#479L,event_month#468,telia_pdnconnectionsmobileipv6addr#494,telia_pdnconnectionsapnambrdl#490L,telia_pdnbearersdluserplanefteidip#474,imsi#470L]
       :  +- RepartitionByExpression [imsi#470L,telia_psn#496L,time#497L], None
       :     +- Relation[child_instance_id#465,event_day#466,event_hour#467,event_month#468,event_year#469,imsi#470L,ingestion_timestamp#471,telia_pdnbearersbeareresttime#472L,telia_pdnbearersdluserplanefteidinterface#473,telia_pdnbearersdluserplanefteidip#474,telia_pdnbearersdluserplanefteidteid#475L,telia_pdnbearersebi#476,telia_pdnbearersgbrguaranteedbitratedl#477L,telia_pdnbearersgbrguaranteedbitrateul#478L,telia_pdnbearersgbrmaxbitratedl#479L,telia_pdnbearersgbrmaxbitrateul#480L,telia_pdnbearerslinkedebi#481,telia_pdnbearerspreemptioncapability#482,telia_pdnbearerspreemptionvulnerability#483,telia_pdnbearersprioritylevel#484,telia_pdnbearersqosqci#485,telia_pdnbearersuluserplanefteidinterface#486,telia_pdnbearersuluserplanefteidip#487,telia_pdnbearersuluserplanefteidteid#488L,telia_pdnconnectionsapn#489,telia_pdnconnectionsapnambrdl#490L,telia_pdnconnectionsapnambrul#491L,telia_pdnconnectionsdefaultbearerebi#492,telia_pdnconnectionsmobileipaddr#493,telia_pdnconnectionsmobileipv6addr#494,telia_pdnconnectionsselectionmode#495,telia_psn#496L,time#497L,ing_time#498L,job_instance_id#499] AvroRelation
       +- Project [psn_key#259L,event_datetime_EET#248,msisdn#258L,ueidentityimeitac#271,md5ueidentityimsi#257,ueidentityimsi#272L,locationinfoeci#252,time#265L,md5msisdn#256,ueidentityimei#270L,rattype_lu#261,locationinfotac#255]
          +- RepartitionByExpression [ueidentityimsi#272L,psn_key#259L,time#265L], None
             +- Project [time#265L,event_datetime_EET#248,md5ueidentityimsi#257,ueidentityimei#270L,ueidentityimeitac#271,msisdn#258L,md5msisdn#256,locationinfotac#255,locationinfoeci#252,rattype_lu#261,psn_key#259L,ueidentityimsi#272L,job_instance_id#251,event_year#281,event_month#282,event_day#283,event_hour#284]
                +- Join Inner, Some((((((job_instance_id#251 = job_instance_id#5) && (event_year#281 = event_year#3)) && (event_month#282 = event_month#2)) && (event_day#283 = event_day#0)) && (event_hour#284 = event_hour#1)))
                   :- Project [time#265L,event_datetime_EET#248,md5ueidentityimsi#257,ueidentityimei#270L,ueidentityimeitac#271,msisdn#258L,md5msisdn#256,locationinfotac#255,locationinfoeci#252,rattype_lu#261,psn_key#259L,ueidentityimsi#272L,job_instance_id#251,event_year#281,event_month#282,event_day#283,event_hour#284]
                   :  +- Relation[charginginfochargingcharacteristics#240,charginginfocharginggatewayaddress#241,charginginfocharginggatewayname#242,charginginfochargingid#243L,dlcontrolplanefteidinterface#244,dlcontrolplanefteidip#245,dlcontrolplanefteidteid#246L,endtime#247L,event_datetime_EET#248,gtpv2causevalue_lu#249,ingestion_timestamp#250,job_instance_id#251,locationinfoeci#252,locationinfomcc_lu#253,locationinfomnc_lu#254,locationinfotac#255,md5msisdn#256,md5ueidentityimsi#257,msisdn#258L,psn_key#259L,ptmsi#260L,rattype_lu#261,recordtype_lu#262,starttime#263L,status#264,time#265L,ueidentitygutimmegi#266,ueidentitygutiplmnid#267,ueidentitygutistmsimmec#268,ueidentitygutistmsimtsmi#269,ueidentityimei#270L,ueidentityimeitac#271,ueidentityimsi#272L,ueidentitystmsimmec#273L,ueidentitystmsimtmsi#274L,ulcontrolplanefteidinterface#275,ulcontrolplanefteidip#276,ulcontrolplanefteidteid#277L,vlaninfovlancfi_lu#278,vlaninfovlanid#279,vlaninfovlanpriority_lu#280,event_year#281,event_month#282,event_day#283,event_hour#284] ParquetRelation
                   +- Project [event_month#2,event_day#0,event_year#3,job_instance_id#5,event_hour#1]
                      +- InMemoryRelation [event_day#0,event_hour#1,event_month#2,event_year#3,ing_year#41,ing_month#42,ing_day#43,ing_hour#44,job_instance_id#5], true, 10000, StorageLevel(true, true, false, false, 1), TungstenAggregate(key=[event_day#0,event_hour#1,event_month#2,event_year#3,ing_year#41,ing_month#42,ing_day#43,ing_hour#44,job_instance_id#5], functions=[], output=[event_day#0,event_hour#1,event_month#2,event_year#3,ing_year#41,ing_month#42,ing_day#43,ing_hour#44,job_instance_id#5]), None
```

Comment: Could you show a little bit of code and tell us more about the data? It could be a cartesian product on one or several keys that are duplicated, but without more information, there is no way to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is one slow task this sounds like there is one key with most of the records. This is known as the skewed join problem, some approaches on solving it are detailed here: [Skewed dataset join in Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40373577/skewed-dataset-join-in-spark).