# Spark AQE not helping with dataset skew join

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, dataset, apache-spark-dataset, skew

I'm facing a problem in spark where 2 skewed datasets takes too long to join. One(or two) of the datasets has skewed data in it and it's used as the join column.

So I enabled spark AQE in the hope of it might help me with skewed dataset join. However when I checked the sql query metrics they don't suggest AQE is helping me with the skew and some of the partitions are still quite large. And when I check the stage status I found a few long running tasks taking hours to complete.

[image: SQL query run metrics screenshot]

I'm quite confused by the behavior of AQE and very surprised to find out that it didn't seem to be helping. Could anyone point out what's wrong here or if I'm missing anything?

btw here are some of my spark configurations:

```
.config("spark.sql.adaptive.enabled", "true") \
.config("spark.sql.adaptive.skewJoin.enabled", "true") \
.config("spark.executor.memory", "32g") \
.config("spark.executor.memoryOverhead", "8g") \
.config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "2000") \
```

Comment: Did you tried considering the broadcast join and salting to enhance performance?

Comment: well, I'd hope spark aqe would automatically help me with that, e.g. dynamically switch to broadcast join or mitigate skewed dataset join. Explicitly using broadcast join or salting the dataset in the code kinda contradicts the idea of letting the framework do it for you no?

Comment: Broadcast is a different property from AQE which you can check in Spark properties.Salting is a manual way to reducethe data skewness by applying uniqueness. May be explain command would help further where the process is actually taking time

Comment: From databrick's official blog about aqe, it states "... AQE skew join optimization detects such skew automatically...It then splits the skewed partitions into smaller subpartitions...". Also it states "AQE now replans the join strategy at runtime based on the most accurate join relation size". So unless I'm understanding it wrong, spark AQE is supposed to do all of that automatically once turned on. And my question is exactly why it didn't do so in my case. [Blog source](https://databricks.com/blog/2020/05/29/adaptive-query-execution-speeding-up-spark-sql-at-runtime.html)

Comment: Did you checked in event timeline?

Comment: Also try persist/caching of datasets before joining and applying filter conditions-https://databricks.com/blog/2015/06/22/understanding-your-spark-application-through-visualization.html

Comment: Sorry but I feel like this is not the perspective I've been looking for. In the post I'm emphasizing on why AQE didn't work, I'm not asking for answers on how to handle data skew manually or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In versions 3.0 to 3.2, AQE skew join optimization is still super rudimentary. If you manually alter the number of partitions then it will be skipped. Likewise, much of AQE will be skipped if you use caching. In 3.3 you can force skew join optimization when you are manually partitioning using config `spark.sql.adaptive.forceOptimizeSkewedJoin`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. So by saying "manually alter the number of partitions then it will be skipped", do you mean a simple repartition() call will make spark skip the optimization, or are you referring to some other kinds of partition altering? Also would you mind explaining a bit more on why these actions will make AQE skip it?

Comment: Basically, if the optimization would introduce an additional shuffle in the plan for the stage then the optimization will be skipped. So if you are causing a shuffle with a repartition and it can't be reconciled with the optimized skew join shuffle then the plan won't be altered.

This is the original commit addressing the issue: https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/4a6b2b9fc8b68d59857c5ee71e817b9b06db5ba8