# Spark simple join not working, work not getting properly distributed among executors

Tags: python, scala, pyspark, memory, apache-spark-sql

Hi I have two df like this:

```
df1
id          items
1    [[c,b,..], [z,x,..],..]
2    [[d,t,..], [q,a,..],..]
.              .
.              .

schema: [('id', 'string'), ('items', 'array<array<string>>')]
Total Records: 157
Total Partition while saving: 20
Total size of data: 700mb

df2
id   rand
1     a
2     b
4     h
.     .
.     .

Total Records: 1.5 Million
Total Partition while saving: 10
Total size of data: 200mb
```

Now I'm applying inner join using `id` col and trying to save the dataframe, but it's taking forever and when I check spark ui:

- I noticed that it's getting stuck after running fix number of Task,
- Also I noticed that task is not getting properly split into executors, like most of the shuffle read size/records are split into 10 executors even though I have more executors

Here's my spark config:

```
spark_config["spark.executor.memory"] = "24G"
spark_config["spark.executor.memoryOverhead"] = "8G"
spark_config["spark.executor.cores"] = "24"
spark_config["spark.driver.memory"] = "10G"
spark_config["spark.sql.shuffle.partitions"] = "50"
spark_config["spark.default.parallelism"] = "50"
spark_config["spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled"] = "true"
spark_config["spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled"] = "true"
spark_config["spark.shuffle.service.enabled"] = "true"
spark_config["spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors"] = "100"
spark_config["spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors"] = "500"
spark_config["spark.submit.deployMode"] = "client"
spark_config["spark.yarn.queue"] = "default"
```

I have tried `increasing-decreasing shufffle-partition and default-parallelism` also tried giving more memory to executors but nothing is working, it's getting stuck after running fix number of task, eg if partition is `100 then it'll get stuck at 76, if partition is 500 then 476 and if 50 then 28`

I have also attached ss of executor and task from ui

All the task where there's Shuflle Read/records it's getting failed
[image]

Where there's no Shuflle Read/records it's getting su
[image]

In executors all the work is getting split into 8-10 executors where few tasks are getting failed after performing some task and other executors doesn't have any work, seems like this is the main problem.
[image]

And where task are getting failed in executors I'm getting this `stdout`

```
#
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
# -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill %p"
#   Executing /bin/sh -c "kill 12155"...
```

Edit:
1)PySpark 2.4.8
2) Joining code:

```
df1 = df1.join(df2, how = 'inner', on = 'id')
```

3. I have 100 executors, I have tried adding and removing them.

Comment: Beside the task splitting looks strange, the GC time seems abnormal too. I have three questions: 1. What is your Spark version? 2. Could you share more about your code, especially related to joining and transformation part? It's great if you can show the DAG too. 3. What's the number of instance of executor?

Comment: @Jonathan please check the edit in question

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's related to data skewing issue. It's unbelievable that 100 executors with 24 cores and 24G memory each can't handle such data volume.

If you can upgrade your version, update it to Spark version 3.x.x and enable the Adaptive Query Execution - AQE (`spark.sql.adaptive.enabled`). AQE did a lot of optimization in SQL query planning, it also optimizes the skew joining problems. You may check [databricks blog](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2020/05/29/adaptive-query-execution-speeding-up-spark-sql-at-runtime.html?source=post_page-----e2934b00b021--------------------------------) and [Spark official docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html?source=post_page-----e2934b00b021--------------------------------#adaptive-query-execution).

If you can't upgrade your version, you may try:

1. Use Broadcast join to broadcast the smaller dataframe to each executor to prevent data shuffling and skewing.
2. Add a column on both sides of the join based on random seeding. You can check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40376978/10445333).